# Adding label data to sankey plot axis with ggalluvial Package

Tags: r, ggplot2, sankey-diagram, ggalluvial

How do I add label names in the white boxes to each of the three axis on the ggalluvial sankey plot from the dataframe? (see image)

Column "Country" has observations for multiple countries. In the example below I am focused on Ireland which has the label "IE". How do I harvest the dataframe for the Country name using the ggplot code below? I will also be doing this task for the "Vaccine" and the "TargetGroup" names so if the solution can include these columns too, I would be grateful. Thank you

Dataframe code and sankey colours - data is from the EU ECDC

```
data <- read.csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/vaccine_tracker/csv/data.csv", na.strings = "", fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
colnames(data)[2] <- "Country"
TestData <- data
Ireland <- subset(TestData, Country == "IE")

Combined <- rbind(Ireland ) #removed other countries for ease of reading

Col1 <- "slateblue2"
Col2 <- "chartreuse2"
Col3 <- "tomato2"
Col4 <- "orange2"
Col5 <- "plum3"
Col6 <- "grey43"
Col7 <- "deeppink"

alpha <- 0.2
```

**This is the sankey code - this is where I am NOT CORRECTLY applying labels to the relevant axis**

```
ggplot(Combined,
       aes(weight = FirstDose, axis1 = Vaccine, axis2 = Country, axis3 = TargetGroup)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Vaccine, color = Vaccine), 
                width = 0.1, alpha = alpha, knot.pos = 0.4) +
  geom_stratum(width = 0.2, color = "black") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Vaccine", "Country", "TargetGroup"))     +
  scale_fill_manual(values  = c(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7)) +
  ggtitle("ECDC Vaccination data") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")
  )
```

This is the image - you can see that the axes boxes are missing labels

[image: sankey without axes labels]

Comment: I think the answer is here `geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE)` but I cannot find any documentation that helps me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out - full code chunk here. I hope this helps someone out

```
ggplot(Combined,
       aes(weight = FirstDose, axis1 = Vaccine, axis2 = Country, axis3 = TargetGroup)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Vaccine, color = Vaccine), 
                width = 0.1, alpha = alpha, knot.pos = 0.4) +
  geom_stratum(width = 0.2, color = "black") +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(deposit)),
            color = "black") + 
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), min.y = 200) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Vaccine", "Country", "TargetGroup"))     +
  scale_fill_manual(values  = c(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7)) +
  ggtitle("ECDC Vaccination data") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",     panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),     axis.text.y = element_blank(),       
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")
  )
```

By adding in these two lines (and I don't fully understand them yet) after the `geom_stratum()` argument. The labels are where I want them. It's not pretty yet.

```
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(deposit)),
            color = "black") + 
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), min.y = 200) +
```

Solution
[image: solution]

The answer was found on this blog post http://corybrunson.github.io/ggalluvial/reference/stat_stratum.html

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. I haven't tried out your data, but are you sure you need both statements? For my data I just needed to add `aes(label = after_stat(count))` to geom_text to get it to work (I needed the count function instead of deposit).